# incomplete implementation xcode buttons to disable buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios6

I am new to Objective C and Xcode so please be patient with me!! I have written a program that controls 5 buttons and 1 reset button.  If any of the 5 buttons are pressed, they should all be disabled (greyed out) until the reset button is pressed.  Here is my attempt:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
    IBOutlet UIButton *button1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button2;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button3;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button4;
    IBOutlet UIButton *button5;
    IBOutlet UIButton *resetButton;
}
    @property(retain,nonatomic)UIButton *button1;
    @property(retain,nonatomic)UIButton *button2;
    @property(retain,nonatomic)UIButton *button3;
    @property(retain,nonatomic)UIButton *button4;
    @property(retain,nonatomic)UIButton *button5;
    @property(retain,nonatomic)UIButton *resetButton;
    - (IBAction)anyButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender;
    - (IBAction)resetPressed:(UIButton *)sender;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, resetButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(IBAction)anyButtonPressed{
    button1.enabled = NO;
    button2.enabled = NO;
    button3.enabled = NO;
    button4.enabled = NO;
    button5.enabled = NO;

}

-(IBAction)resetPressed{
    button1.enabled = YES;
    button2.enabled = YES;
    button3.enabled = YES;
    button4.enabled = YES;
    button5.enabled = YES;

}

@end
```

But it says incomplete implementation next to ViewController and when I press a button in the simulator, it crashes.  Help me please?  Also please suggest any easier ways to implement this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button action method signatures are not correct in your implementation. Change your code to:

```
-(IBAction)anyButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    button1.enabled = NO;
    button2.enabled = NO;
    button3.enabled = NO;
    button4.enabled = NO;
    button5.enabled = NO;
}

-(IBAction)resetPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    button1.enabled = YES;
    button2.enabled = YES;
    button3.enabled = YES;
    button4.enabled = YES;
    button5.enabled = YES;
}
```